# model values are not showing in partial update view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, devextreme

In my web app I have a grid list. I select a row and then click the edit button to show a partial update view (which I use to add new data too) in a popup window. The view shows, but I don't have any values in the textboxes. I use devextreme components, but I think, my issue has nothing to do with it (maybe I'm wrong).

This is the onClick code:

```js
function editrow_onClick() {
        var key = $("#grid").dxDataGrid("instance").getKeyByRowIndex(selectedRowIndex);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/MasterData/Sender/UpdateSender/'+key,
        }).done(function (response) {
            var popup = $("#sender-popup").dxPopup("instance");
            popup.option("contentTemplate", function (content) {
                content.append(response);
            });
            popup.show();
        });
    }
```

If I click the edit button, I get the right url like /MasterData/Sender/UpdateSender/3.

The corresponding controller action looks like this:

```
[Route("{id}")]
    public IActionResult UpdateSender(long SenderId)
    {
        return PartialView("NewSender", SenderRepository.GetSender(SenderId));
    }
```

On top of the controller class I have the corresponging attribute: `[Route("MasterData/[controller]/[action]")]`

I testet id, the action is reached, but the `SenderId` is 0. I would expect f.e. 3. This should be causing the empty view, I think. Why is `SenderId` 0 (the default value)?

I post the update view too, maybe this is the source of the problem (don't bother the `AddSender` action, I plan to change it conditionally, if I get the update data working):

```html
@model Sender

<form asp-action="AddSender" asp-controller="Sender" method="post">
    @using(Html.DevExtreme().ValidationGroup()) { 
        @(Html.DevExtreme().Form<Sender>()
            .ID("form")
            .ColCount(1)
            .Items(items => {
                items.AddSimpleFor(m => Model.Name);
                items.AddSimpleFor(m => Model.Address);
                items.AddSimpleFor(m => Model.ContactPerson);
                items.AddSimpleFor(m => Model.ContactEmail);
                items.AddGroup().Items(groupItem => groupItem.AddSimple().Template(
                @<text>
                    <div style="text-align: right">
                        @(Html.DevExtreme().Button().ID("save").Text("Mentés").Width(100).Type(ButtonType.Success).UseSubmitBehavior(true))
                        @(Html.DevExtreme().Button().ID("cancel").Text("Mégsem").Width(100).Type(ButtonType.Normal).OnClick("close_onClick"))
                    </div>
                </text>));
            })
            .LabelLocation(FormLabelLocation.Top)
            .FormData(Model)
        )
    }
</form>

<script>
    function close_onClick() {
        $("#sender-popup").dxPopup("hide");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Route("{SenderId}")] public IActionResult UpdateSender(long SenderId) { return PartialView("NewSender", SenderRepository.GetSender(SenderId)); }
```

Try replacing **id** with **SenderId**.
Then action method will hit with the desired value.

Comment: Yes, the SenderId has the correct value now, but the textboxes in the view are still empty.